# Linux Mint UI glitch

Tags: linux-mint, nvidia

I have a problem after upgrading and updating on Linux Mint. Every element of the UI
I can think of glitches / flashes on actions: scrolling, hovering, clicking, focusing window, typing, change, etc. It's still usable, but disturbing. It've improved a little bit after disabling some system effects (I followed 5.1 point in [easylinuxtipsproject](https://easylinuxtipsproject.blogspot.com/p/speed-mint.html#ID5.1) instruction). I work on HP Omen laptop, graphic card: nVidia geforce GTX.

Comment: did you by chance enable a development mode of some kind?

Comment: I don't think so. I have seen no such option to select while upgrading.